# Topological $(2n+1)$-dimensional Manifold with ball removed orientable?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose you have a compact, orientable $(2n+1)$-manifold $M$. You take a neighbourhood about a point homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$, and remove a small ball $B$. So the the  boundary of $M\backslash B$ is homeomorphic to $S^{2n}$. Let $N$ be $M\backslash B$ where the antipodal points of the boundary are identified. Determine whether or not $N$ is orientable (ie. the $H_{2n+1}(N)=\mathbb{Z}$)

I know that $N$ has $RP^{2n}$ as the boundary, I'm trying to apply mayer-vietoris but am unsure on how to proceed.

Comment: Dumb question:  Since the Stiefel-Whitney number $\langle w_1^{2n}, [\mathbb{R}P^{2n}]\rangle$ is nonzero for $\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$, it can't be the boundary of a manifold, so $N$ cannot be given the structure of a manifold.  What is your definition of orientable in this case, then?  Further, even if $N$ were a manifold with boundary, $H_{2n+1}(N) \neq \mathbb{Z}$ regardless of whether or not $N$ is orientable.

Comment: If you write (2n+1)- INSIDE of TeX, then the hyphen looks like a minus sign instead of a hyphen, thus: $(2n+1)-$manifold.  But if you put (2n+1) in TeX and the hyphen outside TeX, then it looks like a hyphen, thus: $(2n+1)$-manifold.

Comment: Looking at this 2 years later, I don't think $N$ has $\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$ as a boundary.  For example, if $M = S^3$, then $N$ is the usual ball model of $\mathbb{R}P^3$ with antipodal points identified on the boundary.  That is, $N$ is a just an honest to goodness smooth manifold.  (And, at least in this case, $H_{2n+1}(N) \cong \mathbb{Z}$)